# Errors not shown with babel-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, babeljs

I'm not sure why, but I just ran into a situation in which an object was `undefined` and I tried to call a property on that object. What happend was nothing, except that the console seems to be hanging (no more console message were printed). Now, I run my ES2015 program as follows

```
$> ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./my-app
```

Is this a known issue with babel, is could this be something else ?

Comment: Are you using Promises? They can swallow errors if you haven't configured an `unhandledRejection` handler.

Comment: My application is one big Promise. Ok, thnx for pointing that one out, I'll need to fix that!

Comment: The issue here is of course that I have to do a `catch` on every promise. Is there an easier, more generic solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an [`unhandledRejection`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) handler.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(err){
    console.log(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

otherwise Node's default `Promise` implementation will silently swallow `reject` calls to promises without `.catch` handlers.